# Python 3: capture a matrix return from subprocess with Rscript

Tags: python, r, python-3.x, subprocess

I am using `subprocess` to run a Rscript. The script returns a R matrix. I am using `subprocess.check_output` in Python and get a string. But is there a way to get directly the output matrix in Python?

Thanks

Comment: You should look into [rpy2](https://rpy2.readthedocs.io/en/version_2.8.x/) it is a python package that allow you to transfer object between R and python

Comment: Yes, I tried and in fact have a lot of problems with ``rpy2`` that I posted in stackoverflow.

Comment: An other solution is to write your result from R into a csv and load it in python

Comment: Yes that in fact what I did - but I think it is not the best solution because I/O speed should slow the whole process.

Answer (score 1):

Exchanging objects between two languages is not an easy task.

**The generic solution**

This solution works for all languages:

1. You launch your script
2. After computation you write your results in a generic format. For example .csv or .txt or .json
3. You reload the result in the other language

**Regarding R and python**

There is an existing package to do that: [rpy](https://rpy2.readthedocs.io/en/version_2.8.x/) but it might be tricky to use, and some times errors are not quite explicit (because as I said, it is tricky to exchange object between two languages).